# ipad image swiper like iTune's horizontal library

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ipad

I need to make an ipad app which includes an image swiper but not a regular one. I need it to be like itunes library swiper when the device rotation is horizontal. is there any way to do it with objective c or should i do it with html and javascript?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some experience in using [iCarousel](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/icarousel) by Nick Lockwood. It is very easy to use with several build in effects and also not so hard to modify.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean coverflow?

You could use [this library on CocoaControls called TapKu](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/tapku-coverflow)

There are also a few others [here](http://cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=coverflow)

Answer (score 0):

You can check this HTML+JavaScript implementation http://idangero.us/sliders/swiper/plugins/3dflow.php